# imac mid 2011 install os x from usb drive

Tags: macos, imac, apple-id

I have a problem here, I got iMac mid-2011 with fresh HDD. I want to install mac os x el capitan from USB drive, but when I click option button on my keyboard there is no HDD or USB drive shown. only internet recovery and wifi connection. when I try internet recovery to reinstall os x, there is lion os x but when entering my app store data it says " this item is temporarily unavailable " please help. thanks in advance

Comment: It has a "Fresh HDD" - does that mean you have the old HDD with macOS installed or is it completely dead or wiped clean?

Comment: thanks for reply. its fresh new HDD and it doesnt appears :( and bootable USB so when pressing option key after restart, only wifi connection on startup menu and after some time internet recovery

Comment: It won't appear until you format it with Disk Utility.  I'm still not clear as to why Internet Recovery won't work - the question is a little confusing regarding this and how it relates to the App Store.  Also, did you verify that the USB is, in fact, bootable?